# SpecFlow building steps out of existing steps

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a set of base steps in SpecFlow that do simple things like enter text and validate fields. I want so that these base steps can be used by non technical testers in creating higher level steps made out of these base steps. They should not need to know how to code or how to implement step definitions or how to use selenium at all. All they need to do is define a step in English that calls other base steps. Then they can repeat the process and make more steps out of the ones they just defined. This how I want automation to occur where I am so that non technical testers can create tests in English only, while coding can be done by someone else.

Does SpecFlow support this? From what I can see you can define a step to use other steps in code (in the step definition bindings), but I cant see where you do something like this in the feature file itself, so no code is involved? Tools like Fitnesse are very good when offering this kind of functionality.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow doesn't support this.

You could construct a test that uses many simple steps, but there is no way to map a single step to many (unless you use code).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at something like http://gherkineditor.codeplex.com/ which is designed to support the writing of Feature files without an IDE.

I've blogged about getting started and working with Specflow on the [JUST EAT Tech blog](http://tech.just-eat.com/2014/03/21/acceptance-testing-with-specflow/)